# Qt- What is the difference between new QThread(this) and new QThread()?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I would like to know what difference there is between `new QThread(this)` and `new QThread()` and how this would influence the behaviour of my code when using [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#QThread).

Comment: Do you know what [parents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html) are in Qt?

Comment: The difference is who takes the QThread object ownership. passing 'this' as parent means the the 'this' parent should release the QThread object resources.  it wont influence the behaviour of QThread just the resource management.

Comment: @Simon besides the note in `~QThread` vis destroying running threads

Answer (score 6):

The parent of a [`QThread`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#QThread) does not make any difference *on who executes what*.
It is just the classic parent-child relationship in Qt, the [Object-Tree](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html), meaning the parent takes ownership of the QThread instance and will delete its child when it gets deleted.

---

What is important when it comes to threads in Qt is

- Where do you create a QObject instance (by default the object belongs to the thread that created it)
- The parent of a QObject instance (when you do a [`QObject::moveToThread(QThread *targetThread)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) all the children of the object are moved too)

Because : the slots of a QObject are executed in the thread that it belongs to.